# How to split on unicode character in java

Tags: java, unicode

I have a String in java that looks something like this -

```
“id\uFF1Aabc123, ip\uFF1A127:0:0:1”
```

How do I split this in java based on the \uFF1A? So far I have tried this -

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\uFF1A", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
System.out.println(p.split(s)[0]);
```

And it just returns back the entire string.

Comment: Why are you using `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` when your regex doesn't have any character class?

Comment: @Andreas - Then which class should I use? .split() method is not working for me

Comment: Seems you have no clue what a regex "character class" is. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question code is working fine. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/EZpcDj).

Answer (score 3):

Your code works.

However, you can just use the `String.split` method:

```
String s = "id\uFF1Aabc123, ip\uFF1A127:0:0:1";

String[] splitted = s.split("\uFF1A");
System.out.println(splitted[0]);
System.out.println(splitted[1]);
System.out.println(splitted[2]);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/Foruoq)